# Reference Book for supremum and infimum theorems

Tags: order-theory

For my work I need many of the very easy and basic properties of suprema and infima. While they are all pretty easy to prove, I would prefer to refer to a standard text book. However I did not find one and worse, do not know how to search for one.

I am interested in properties for partially ordered sets like

$A\subseteq B \Rightarrow \inf B \le \inf A$

$\inf \bigcup A=\inf \{\inf a|a\in A\}$

And for sets with a "$+$", and an inverse $-$ (i.e. $-x \le -y \leftrightarrow x\ge y$):

$\inf X=-\sup (-X)$

$\inf (X+m) = (\inf X) +m $

And the equivalent for functions into such sets ($f: Y \rightarrow X$):

$\inf_{y\in Y} f(y)=-\sup_{y\in Y} -f(y)$

and so on...

Is there like a "reference handbook"?

Comment: OK. That's what I am doing right now!

Answer (score 3):

As far as the standard order on the real line is concerned, most of the above properties are (at least) stated in

Stanisław Łojasiewicz, *An introduction to the theory of real functions*. With contributions by M. Kosiek, W. Mlak and Z. Opial. Third edition. Translated from the Polish by G. H. Lawden. Translation edited by A. V. Ferreira. A Wiley-Interscience Publication. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd., Chichester, 1988. x+230 pp. ISBN: 0-471-91414-2, [MR0952856](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0952856), [Zbl 0653.26001](https://zbmath.org/0653.26001).

Analogous properties of sup are proved there; those for inf may be left as exercises. I do not have a copy at hand right now to give an accurate account.

Answer (score 3):

This question is rather old and the OP seems to be not among us anymore, but still:

These things are of course found in Bourbaki's *Éléments de mathématique,* especially in E.III.1.9 and A.VI.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Egbert Harzheim. Ordered Sets. Springer, 2005

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that. Did not find any of the above theorems. Are they in there?